# Multiple definition error while linking two object files with same definition

Tags: c++, c, object, linker, shared

Basically my prob is this :

I have a header file - `foo.h` with a structure pointer `human *person = NULL` in it. The definition for structure `human` is in another header included within foo.h . I am creating a shared object file `game.so` using `foo.h` and few other headers and cpps.

Now , I have two different cpp files - `a.cpp` and `b.cpp` which include the header foo.h.
I am creating an object file `a.o` separately and `b.o` separately.
I am linking both the object file and `game.so` for creating another shared object file `tennis.so`and while doing so , am getting multiple definition for the "person". I am aware that the multiple definition error is because `a.o` contains the structure definition for `person` , so does `b.o`.

I have used `#pragma once` in `foo.h` already. `a.o` is getting compiled separately and `b.o` is getting compiled separately. so i dont think #pragma once or ifdef will be useful here because both `a.cpp` and `b.cpp` includes `foo.h`

I cant change the structure defintion in `foo.`h to any other cpp file due to some dependencies while creating `game.so`

Is there any other way to resolve the multiple definition error I get while creating `tennis.so` ?

Comment: There is no such thing as multiple definition link error for a struct. Please post exact code and build commands to reproduce the situation, plus the exact compiler output.

Comment: I couldn't post the exact code as it is little confidential. Is there anything else I can do ?

Comment: You can create an MCVE ([MCVE]).  That will reproduce the problem but not contain anything confidential.  It sounds like your header doesn't declare the variable; it defines the variable.  Therefore, each file that includes the header contains a definition, preventing them being linked together.  Simple rule of thumb: variables declared in headers should be declared with keyword `extern`.

Comment: @M.M I have modified the question a bit. Please look at it now and see if u can help me.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Its a structure pointer Joanathan .

Comment: No illustration of the code in `foo.h` — nothing we can do to help.  You're on your own until you provide the code that shows the problem; that's the MCVE I referred to.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler alright Joanathan. Let me try to get back with a code to reproduce.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to make sure the `person` variable is only defined once. To do that, you need to only declare that variable in `foo.h`:

```
extern human *person;
```

Then, in `foo.cpp`, you define it:

```
human *person = NULL;
```

You then include `foo.o` in the object files that make up `game.so`.

Comment: Let me try this out Nikos.

Comment: This has worked out Nikos. Thanks a ton for the help :)

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be confusing DECLARATION with DEFINITION. Your header should DECLARE the structure, your C/C++ will then use such declaration to define variables or refer to instances of such definition[s].

Comment: No Ron . Am clear with DEFINITION and DECLARATION. Structure definitions can be within header and it shouldn't create multiple definition error as pointed out by M.M. I very well go with your point that definitions shouldnt be in headers and thats why I have mentioned I am unable to remove the definitions from header due to some dependencies.

Comment: Your revised question shows that you actually duplicate VARIABLE definition (human). The human variable should be defined just once. References to it should use extern to avoid the redundancy. Why is the variable definition (i.e. assignment) takes place in a header and not in the module which should "own" the variable? If/when a variable is defined in a header, it should normally be protected with an #ifdef _FROM_DEFINE_MODULE (definition) #else (extern declaration) #endif

Comment: Yeah ok Ron. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Yeah the extern usage has helped Ron. Thank you :)